# UILabel multilines are not working

Tags: ios, xcode, uilabel

I have been using `UILabel` for showing multiple lines of text in many projects by setting `numberOfLines = 0`. Today I came across weird behaviour `UILabel` despite having set correct settings to show multiple lines, `UILabel` is not expanding its height. Even setting explicit number of lines of 2, 3 etc is not working.

**UILabel Settings:**

[image]

**Constraints**

[image]

I am not sure if something has gone wrong or updated in Swift4.

Comment: I would assume you have added a height constraint or you are limiting the height in some other way.

Comment: No I didn't add height constraint

Comment: Make sure that `content compression resistence priority` for `height` is set to `1000`.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace 0 by 2 in lines attribute
[image]

Comment: Actually, 0 should have worked. From Apple _"Setting a value of 0 allows the label to use as many lines as necessary"_. I think the default use to be 0, now the default is 1.